# Can't use cont_any for multiterm search with Ransack (Rails 5)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin, ransack

I'm using Ransack for search, which is working fine. But I would like the user to be able to search for multiple keywords in the same search input field.

For example if I have blog "I live in Ohio", I would like the user to be able to search "I Ohio", and it would find the blog. I tried the following which doesn't work:

```
  <%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
      <%= f.search_field :title_or_description_cont_any %>
      <% f.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

And here is my controller:

```
   def index
     @search = Blog.ransack(params[:q])
     @blogs = @search.result
   end
```

I would have thought cont_any would work, but for some reason it doesn't?

---

UPDATE: I'm using also active_admin, I don't know if that matters?

Comment: Did you try `matches_any`?

Comment: I tried matches_any, but it doesn't work :-/

Comment: In their dcumentation, they have used `search_field`, did you try that ? `<%= f.search_field title_or_description_cont %>`. Can you also share you `form` ?

Answer (score 1):

I too had this question (also Rails 5). What finally worked for me was using *_cont_all and passing it an array of search terms.

View: (generic Rails form_with so I can just send params, because our use cases are too long/wordy/complex for the ransack search form to be easily readable!)

```html
= form_with url: book_search_path, method: :get do |f|
   
  .input-label Book Title
  = f.text_field :title_terms,  value: @title_terms
  
  . . .
```

Then in my controller, I used *_cont_all, but passed it an array of terms split on spaces.
(Note that I'm not using params[:q], I just create an empty hash and call it 'q', then pass q to ransack -- Book.ransack(q))

```html
# make an array of terms, split on spaces
  q[:book_titles_cont_all] = params[:title_terms].split(' ')
```

Finally, I pass q to Book.ransack(q) and send the results to my view.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have to pass to the predicate an array of words, _cont_any or cont_all or other forms of them.

I had fixed it using split string like the code shown below.

```
if params[:q].present? and params[:q][:name_cont_all].present?
  words = params[:q][:name_cont_all].split(" ")
  params[:q][:name_cont_all] = words
end
```

this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I think what Shuaib did was the right way to go, a more complete answer would be:

```rb
  def index
    q = params[:q]
    if q&.key?(:title_or_description_cont_any) && q[:title_or_description_cont_any].is_a?(String)
      q[:title_or_description_cont_any] = q[:title_or_description_cont_any].split
    end
    @search = Blog.ransack(params[:q])
    @blogs = @search.result
  end
```

This checks the existence of the field in question and split it if it is a String.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like the following

```
def index
  @search = Blog.ransack(params[:q])
  @blogs = @search.result(distinct: true)
end
```

Your form should look like this,

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
  <%= f.search_field :title_or_description_cont %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Still can't get it to work, I tried also cont_any :-/

Answer (score 0):

`Title` and `description` need to be actual fields in your database. For example if you created a Post model with fields in it containing `header`, `subtitle` and `shortDescription`, you will need to use these fields instead of `title` and `description`.

```
<%= f.input :title_or_description_cont_any %>
<%= f.input :title_or_description_cont %>
```

something like this:

```
<%= f.input :header_or_shortDescription_cont_any %>
```